# Webpage copy file between folders

Tags: javascript, html5-filesystem

We have a web app when users can select a file on their pc through an input type file object. We get the result of their choosing and store the path info into db for further use, but we now also want to copy the file to a shared folder we have disposed for this purpose (this is a internal tool, so we want all files from all users stored on the same place), so the path that is stored on database points to the shared common folder. So in the future, when the file has to be accessed, it's done on the controlled shared folder, no in the local user copy.

So now we need to copy the file handler selected by the user to a remote folder known to our system, but we don't know exactly how to do this. We MUST do this on client code, as the page is part of an ERP solution where we only can develop small webpages with HTML and javascript. We are wondering if FileSystemAccess API is the way to go, and our main question at this point is how to get a FileSystemDirectoryHandler for our destination folder without having to open a folder picker window (the users won't know remote folder's path).

Any insight on this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: _"We MUST do this on client code"_ - client JS will have no access to your service file system, nor should it. [`FileSystemAccess`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API) will only ever be able to access the user's file system (with permission)

Comment: @evolutionxbox maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. This is a tool for internal use inside our company. The destination folder is within user's network, although we want the system to be fully transparent to them.

Comment: @Bardo I don't think the network accessibility is the point. But the actual lack of support for this kind of operations with client side JS. If is a requeriment to do it in javascript you may as well start doing google searchs for nodeJS servers accesing the file system. And then work it as a your regular frontend-backend app.
I mean just do it with nodeJS and open some endpoints with express to call your nodeJS code from your ERP.

Comment: @root we've enabled an apache server wich serves the files (they are mainly images) directly to browsers through the paths we store on database. I'm starting to wonder if it will be wiser to just enable a server-side approach to save this folders on that apache server, so our client code could call a service which receives the selected file and stores it on place.

Comment: @Bardo any service as long as it is server side running on the machine (or network if you figure out how to move the files horizontally via LAN) where your shared folder is (maybe be your apache server since you already have that piece of infrastructure). It may be user prompt with a button on your UI. I would perform the second service call upon finishing uploading the original file, no user interaction, but since you may already have tons of files it may be wise to enable the service to be called massively.